# Using json file or another method to cache database entries?

Tags: php, mysql, json, caching, memcached

I have several informations stored in my database, which will not change when the site got refreshed. For example the main homepage settings:

- Title of the page
- Homeurl
- PayPal address
- E-Mail address
- etc.

I have a class called "Homepage" and this class always queries the db to get these informations. Now I want to cache these things, so that I only have to query one time this informations. Should I use a flat json file, which stores this informations for me and others? or should I use the PHP function apc_store? Or is there another good resolution for my problem? Is it possible to cache my PHP PDO class?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Considering how small the storage of those strings will be, I would recommend using the APC to store the data.

Comment: Are you wanting to save this data between user visits?

Comment: Why do you want to cache? Is there a performance issue?

Comment: Well I tried to use apc, but most of the webserver of our customers dont have it installed... And I want to cache for all users, cause this information will be changed in the administration center and there i could reset a file and store it new for my behaviour. I just tried it. I used 10,000 times a SQL query and 10,000 one SQL query and stored it as a json object in a file. The SQL took: 19.8131 seconds and the SQL + file took 1.8131 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options. You could use flat file storage but most caching methods are faster than reading from the disk.

Have a look at these to name a few:

- [Memcache](http://memcached.org/)
- [Redis](http://redis.io/)
- [APC](https://www.php.net/apc/)

You could even use a noSQL database such as [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) as a caching layer.